# T-test in a single sample to check differences between difference choices selected

Tags: t-test

Lets assume a hypothetical survey question (given below):

Please rate your satisfaction with stack exchange website (on a 5 points rating scale):
Note: This question was asked to 100 people and below is the break-up of responses:

Answers:

**option 1**: 5 people (5%)

**option 2**: 10 people (10%)

**option 3**: 5 people (5%)

**option 4**: 38 people (38%)

**option 5**: 42 people (42%)

Now, I can say that 42% is higher than 38% so more people are satisfied with the website. But is the difference of 4% points really significant at 95% confidence?

Basically, how can I apply a z-test of proportions to derive an answer to this problem? In case there is completely different solution to this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if the frequency (or probability) of answering a given option differs from a given distribution, you might be interested in doing a [qui-square test for the homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic).
$$
\chi^2_{df=n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(O_i - E_i)^2}{E_i} =  N \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\left(O_i/N - p_i\right)^2}{p_i} 
$$

Where $df$ are the degrees of freedom, $n$ is the number of categories (note that $n$ is not the number of datapoints), $O_i$ is the number of answers in category $i$ (note that it is the number of answers, not the relative frequency) and $E_i$ is the number of expected answers if your null hypothesis was true.

For instance, if you assumed in the null hypothesis that all answers were equally likely and that you were asking 100 persons, then $E_i=20$ for $i \in \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \} $. In your example, the computations would give:

$$
\chi^2_{df=4} = \frac{(5 - 20)^2}{20} + \frac{(10 - 20)^2}{20} + \frac{(5 - 20)^2}{20} + \frac{(38 - 20)^2}{20} + \frac{(42 - 20)^2}{20}
$$

You obtain a conclusion by looking at the qui-square table for 4 degrees of freedom.

---

**Edit:**

If you select the subsample of your data that answered to option 4 or 5, you'll get:

$$H_0: p_4 = p_5 = 50%$$
$$H_0: p_4 \neq p_5 \quad \quad %$$

In this setting, we have:
$$
O_4 = 38 \\
O_5 = 42 \\
N = 80
$$

And if the null hypothesis were true we would expect to find:
$$
E_4 = p_4 N = 0.5 \times 80 = 40 \\
E_5 = p_5 N = 0.5 \times 80 = 40
$$

Therefore
$$
\chi^2_{df=1} = \frac{(38-40)^2}{40} + \frac{(42 - 40)^2}{40}
$$

Note that in case you intend to do several comparissons like this, it is advisable to use a [family-wise error control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures).

By the way, in the case of a $2 \times 2$ table, you can also use [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).

Comment: Thanks Ertxiem, but probably this might answer another question (and not exactly what I require). It can answer that not all the responses are equally probable. But I need to understand that can with 95% confidence, I can cull out the insight that: option 5 is more preferred over option 4?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your question.

Comment: This actually can serve as a solution..!! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If you think it's appropriate, you may mark one of the answers as accepted (there is a green button).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can recompute the proportions, based on the total number of persons that voted for these two groups?
so you would compare 38 out of 80 (47.5%) to 42 on 80 (52.5%). 
In such case it would be possible to use the classical t.test on proportions. You might however have the issue of multiple comparisons if you perform several tests.

It might exist a possibility to make a complete model and then run post-hoc tests, like a glm but I don't know how to do with the unit of 'points'. I don't know if we can consider the points of the options as a valuated variable.

Comment: Thanks glagla, still I am not sure that recalculation of proportions can actually help in applying z-test. Perhaps, what I can do is perform a hypothesis test with H0 = recalculated proportion of option 5 is > 50%. This might make it a one-sample z-test of proportion!

Comment: Right, I guess that the issue here is that those two values come from the exact same group. One sample test is maybe an option, but I still feel uncomfortable with this approach. I think it would be much better to model the entire dataset using a multinomial test  (multinomial.test in R)